# Why edit must be at least 6 characters?

Tags: discussion, editing

If i want to edit a typo, now i just can't because of this limit.

So what is the reason for this limit?
And what is the way to correct typo, do i really need to do any more editing if all i want to do is change 2 letters order?

Answer (score 4):

If it's only one typo, should you really be editing the post?

Sometimes the answer is yes, and we trust [users with 1000 reputation](https://music.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) to make that distinction.

For users with less rep, and in general, we prefer substantial edits.  Improve grammar, spelling, and clarity; when needed, edit in info from the poster's comments.  And so on.

Note that you can always edit your own posts.

For more information, see [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)

Comment: It should be noted that one additional reason we require at least 6 characters only for suggested edits is because those require approval. It's fine to spend your own time to make such minor typo fixes, but requiring someone else to look at it is not desirable. It was also the case that a lot of the times people had to approve these 1-3 character typo fixes, there was so much else that *could* have been edited, which is even more time spent by the reviewer doing what the editor *Should* have done.

Comment: Yes i would really be editting the post, I'm this kind of person :) Actually i've tried it twice. Second time it was because i've forgot i failed at the first attempt. That was the reason to post this post.

Maybe edits less than 6 characters and/or marked as typo (checkbox next to the summary field?) could be not reviewd?

Comment: @Hubert The ability to mark an edit as minor has been proposed a several times and rejected.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers

Comment: I disagree with this. This is a music site; what if you were posting a small tablature or chord progression, then mistyped a number/letter? One typo can certainly take away a ton of meaning.

Comment: @enthdegree Actually those kind of edits are explicitly discouraged, same as editing code on [SO].  If the OP makes that kind of mistake it's impossible to know what they intended and you're just as likely to introduce a mistake as correct it.  For example, say they wrote "An E Major chord is E-G-B".  Did they mean to say "E Minor" or "G#"?  Best to leave a comment requesting that the OP clarify what they meant.  (Note that you can always edit your own posts, not matter how minor the edit.)

Comment: @GraceNote It should be updated to "users with 2000 reputation". (I had to @ someone who could edit the post because suggested edits are not allowed on meta sites and the author is deleted.)